# Groups of edges and select in visNetwork in R

Tags: r, visnetwork

Is there a way to create groups of edges of a network? And can I select a group of edges that shows selected edges with nodes? Visualize with different colors and titles on an arrow is working manually.

This works well with nodes like tutorial shows in the middle of that page: https://datastorm-open.github.io/visNetwork/options.html